# How can I set the network.http.response.timeout in Firefox with javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, configuration

The `network.http.response.timeout` was changed from not being set in Firefox version 28 to a default limit of 300 (5 minutes) in version 29. ([see this blog entry at morgb.blogspot.de](http://morgb.blogspot.de/2014/05/firefox-29-and-http-response-timeout.html)).

I would like to change it back to a higher value, if needed with the help of a Firefox-Addon.

Or add a warning to my web-application (which needs the longer timeout for several reasons).

Comment: Or do I have to reprogram my web-app so only `XMLHttpRequests` use such long loading-times?

Comment: Also, you can check the answer at: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/47754398/1841710](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47754398/1841710)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an addon called "response-timeout-24-hours" with the [addon-sdk](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK) and put this in your `main.js`

```
const {Cc,Ci} = require("chrome");
var pref = Cc["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIPrefBranch);
console.log(pref.setIntPref("network.http.response.timeout", 3600*24));
console.log("timeout set to "+pref.getIntPref("network.http.response.timeout")+"s by response-timeout-24-hours");
```

Comment: I created this addon here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/response-timeout-24-hours/

Comment: Still todo: [How do I check if the addon is installed with javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23812866)

Comment: I have a problem now: the add-on wasn't accepted with the following reason: *"Add-ons which change critical settings must revert the changes when disabled or uninstalled. You should also make the changes in the default, rather than the user, branch."*