# Can I change a config value in firefox with an addon?

Tags: firefox-addon

How is it possible to program an Addon that changes a certain config value in Firefox, that usually is only accessible via `about:config`?

Is there a template I could use? Or Do I have to start from scratch?

Comment: config file for firefox's `about:config` is a simple javascript file located in the user profile. Look for `pref.js` on your computer. It is easily modified via scripting, so it could surely be done with an addon as well

Comment: Please ignore @Ploutox's suggestion and do **not** mess with the file yourself.

Comment: @nmaier Why is that ? It is quite easy to do and quite common as well, at least in Unix environment

Comment: @Ploutox Because add-ons have a dedicated and safe API to query and manipulate preferences. My answer will be up shortly.

Comment: Here's a template that i use that gets notified whenever a pref changes (via observer) and offers an onChange function, I don't have any documentation on it, which i need to write some day. https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/e0d3c21ab38822fbfd17

Comment: @Ploutox: PS: Also, modifying the file from an add-on while the browser is running isn't safe in general. The preferences will not be reloaded until a browser restart and might be overwritten in the mean time by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the [Preferences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences) documentation and API reference, in particular [Adding preferences to an extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Adding_preferences_to_an_extension) and [Code Snippets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Preferences).
Just to be clear: The `nsIPreference*` APIs can be used to query/modify any preference, not just add-on specific ones.

SDK users should use [`simple-prefs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-prefs#Getting_and_setting_preferences) (for add-on prefs), and/or [`preferences/service`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/preferences_service).

Comment: I used the Add-on SDK now and I created this plugin now: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/response-timeout-24-hours/ using `Cc["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIPrefBranch).setIntPref("network.http.response.timeout", 3600*24)` as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783375/how-can-i-display-the-network-http-response-timeout-in-firefox-with-javascript)