# Increase timeout limit in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Internet speed at work is very limited, and because of this I can't load several useful pages, like Trello, Bitbucket, Slack and so on.

Chrome console shows me a long list timeout errors like `GET https://..... net::ERR_TIMED_OUT`.

I was wondering if there is any way to change timeout settings in Chrome.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

- **Chrome**: It is [not possible](https://superuser.com/a/633649) to change the timeout settings in Chrome.
- **Firefox**: You can set the value of `network.http.connection-timeout` in `about:config`
- **IE**: It's possible to change the timeout behavior in the [windows registry](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/813827/how-to-change-the-default-keep-alive-time-out-value-in-internet-explor).
- **Safari**: There is a safari extension [SafariNoTimeout](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/11457/safarinotimeout) to extend the timeout from 60s to 10min.

Comment: so we shouldn't automate tests in Chrome that takes more than 5 mins to look for resources? Chrome devs should look into this

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, and have figured out a way to avoid it.

Use fetch!

I do not exactly know why this works, but it does.
We use swagger when testing our api's, and saw that it never times out.

That lead us to try converting our xhr-request into a fetch-request, in addition to expanding our gateway-timeout etc.

And it works! Chrome doesn't timeout after a minute.

Comment: What exactly does that statement "use fetch" mean in the context of using Chrome as an end user? Not sufficient as an answer, in my opion.

Answer (score 0):

update 24-10-2022:

```
webBrowser = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, chromeOptions, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```